# Is there a thin framework in PHP I can use?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks

I'm looking for a thin web framework in PHP5 to start my project. I have come across some popular frameworks like Symhony, Zend, CodeIgniter... but they seem too complicated and their source code are too long to read. Is there a light framework out there I can use?
(I know some OOP, MVC in PHP)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's your 'no framework' PHP framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694929/whats-your-no-framework-php-framework)

Comment: all the frames works seem more complex than just using php. IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say Codeigniter is about as light as you are going to get, It's fairly convention-less and has proven to be the lightest in terms of overhead.

It is simple and well documented.

Comment: CI is the my first choice to do some thing, it took me hardly an hour to set up a guestbook with all the validations and this and that using CI. Piece of Cake not like CakePHP where you would have to follow conventions.

Comment: thanks. CI looks mature and has a big community, I will check this guy out http://thinphp.com and go back to CI if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

My choice of vote is for CODEIGNITER , because easy to use and build applications and rich documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[MicroMVC](http://micromvc.com/) for sure.

As advertised:

> It offers Model, Library, Controller,
>   Function, and View management. Plus
>   other features like URI Routing,
>   hooks/plugins, file uploads, database
>   abstraction, captcha creation, and
>   more! If you are new the
>   Model/View/Controller world of OOP

All under 150kb!

Answer (score 0):

I too agree with @jondavidjohn. I started with codeigniter and really impressesed with its simple well documented syntax. If you are starting framework for the first time, As for me  CodeIgniter is the best choice. Give it a try http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/ ...

Comment: Next time, when you agree with someone, you should post it as a comment to existing answer (link "add comment" below an answer) rather than as new answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I find Cakephp Framework very addicted for me.................u could check it out

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for Kohana 3 - http://kohanaframework.org/

The documentation sucks but it's very lightweight, there's a good community (even on SO), it's more simple than Symfony and more powerful than CodeIgniter (the first version of Kohana was based on CodeIgniter)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys.

I love CI too. I also googled and found [this one](http://thinphp.com). It looks promising, let's see how it works out, will come back to CI if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [PHP Frameworks](http://www.phpframeworks.com) site, where you can fully compare all kinds of PHP frameworks and help you choose the right php framework for your project. They offer [PHP Frameworks comparison](http://www.phpframeworks.com/php-framework-comparison/), [top 10 frameworks](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/), [reviews](http://www.phpframeworks.com/review-php-frameworks/), [forum](http://www.phpframeworks.com/forum/), etc.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I found success with Kohana 2.3 (the later versions don't work as well IMHO) as it has a very simple MVC structure, it runs fairly quickly, and it is OO. It was based off of CodeIgniter.

However, I would pick a framework and stick with it, paying more attention to designing your application with a good understanding of MVC. Head First Design Patterns (http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124) helped me understand why MVC was useful and how to implement it. Good luck!

Comment: Kohana 2.3 is deprecated, don't tell people to use it :3